# R how to cast string to a vector

Tags: r, vector

I am still a beginner in R and I can't find an answer to my question:

I use a string:

```
string1="c('T-shirt', 'Polo', 'Pull')"
```

And I need my object string1 to be a vector.

Comment: Hi, can you edit your question with the output of `dput(string1)` please.

Comment: if you use `c` it will only return vector and not string.

Comment: Also, if you can be clear about what you want - your title requests a`list`, but the question a `vector`. In r these are two different things.

Comment: Thank you very much !!! 
I was looking for the function dput()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can evaluate the expression in the string using

`eval(parse(text=string1))`

result:
`[1] "T-shirt" "Polo"    "Pull"`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want the final output to be. If you want string1 to be a vector of strings, the right syntax should be

```
string1 <- c("T-shirt", "Polo", "Pull")
```

Please clarify if you want a different output

Answer (score 0):

You can do by both ways

```
eval(parse(text=string1))
```

or

```
c <- gsub("\\(|\\)|c|'", "", string1)
d <- strsplit(c,",")
e <- d[[1]]
e
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with `str_extract` without using the `eval(parse`.

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(string1, "(?<=')[[:alpha:]-]+")[[1]]
#[1] "T-shirt" "Polo"    "Pull"
```

#### data

```
string1="c('T-shirt', 'Polo', 'Pull')"
```